# Jump to given number in fixed least number of steps in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a function where we need to jump to the end of given input `m` while jumping with fixed jump length `n`. Apart from `n` length jumps, we can also increment in steps of 1 to reach our destination. We need to find the fewest number of steps to reach the destination.

Example: If the input is `(9,2)` the output would be `5`, as we would jump 4 times in steps of length 2 from `0`, plus 1 time in a step of length 1, to reach `9`.
Below is the function I wrote:

```
 def flagjump(flag,jmp_height):
     jumps=0
     if flag==jmp_height:
         jumps=1
     elif (flag%jmp_height)<jmp_height:
         jumps=(flag/jmp_height) + (flag%jmp_height)
     elif (flag/jmp_height)==jmp_height:
         jumps=flag/jmp_height
     return int(jumps)
```

I would like to see how to optimize/improve the function above.

Comment: Are you allowed to jump *past* your destination?  So for (9,5), you could jump 5 twice and then jump *back* 1.

Comment: We can jump only by the given step size or in increments of 1. No jumping backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, this can actually be simplified as follows:

```
jumps = m // n
jumps += m % n
```

Also, for your return you do not need to parse `jumps` as an int since it was initialized as 0 and is already a number. The entire function could be written as:

```
def flagjump(flag, jmp_height):
  jumps = flag // jmp_height
  jumps += flag % jmp_height
  return jumps
```

To clarify the math, the `flag // jmp_height` takes your length and divides by your jump length but ignores the remainder. This is how many times you can "jump", for example: `9/2 == 4.5` but `9//2 == 4`. `flag % jmp_height` calculates the remainder of that division, or how many "steps of one" you would have to take: `9%2 == 1`. When added together, you get your answer of `5`.

Answer (score 3):

You've written code to simulate making the jumps.  However, you can get the result with simple arithmetic.

You need `int(m/n)` long jumps; the remainder of this division is the quantity of short jumps.

```
long_jumps = flag // jmp_height
short_jumps = flag % jmp_height
return long_jumps + short_jumps
```

Of course, you can combine those into one `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers have explained, you can simply solve this by integer dividing the two numbers and adding the quotient and remainder.

The most efficient way to do this is by using [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)ming the results:

```py
def flagjump(flag, jmp_height):
    return sum(divmod(flag, jmp_height))
```